# how to get values from get,set and methods with return in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

All method that I can call from service return void.

But I've got in those classes(WCF service) get set methods and method with return. How to get values from such methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Silverlight communication is asynchronous. You must assign a callback to the completed event handler. See [How to: Access a Service from Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197937%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for some code samples.

Comment: So CompletedEventArgs it is the result from method?

Comment: The result of the method is held in the Result property of the EventArgs.

Answer (score 1):

You probably enabled asynchronous calls on the service. You can register for the according events or provide a callback delegate when calling the methods on your proxy.

Comment: Yes. All method are like this MainMethodAsync(),FistAsync()